# Wrong answer in c++

Tags: c++, string, algorithm

You are given a DNA sequence, and few enzymes. Suppose, a DNA sequence goes like this : **ATGCTGCTATGCATGCAGTGACT**, and you are given enzymes which can remove AT and GC sequences. Thereby, you need to remove all occurrences of **AT** from the DNA first and then reform the DNA and apply the next enzyme to remove all occurrences of GC. The output of the problem would be the string you get at last reforming the pieces which are not removed by these enzymes.

**Input**

The first line of input consists of an integer n that denotes the number of enzymes. The first line has the DNA sequence. The next T lines has the input `B1, B2, B3... Bn`.

**Output**

For given input DNA sequence, output a single line containing the final reformed DNA that is formed by repeatedly removing all the occurrences of B1, B2, B3... Bn from A.

In case the DNA is completely consumed print 0 to indicate that there is no DNA left.

```
Constraints

1 <= n <= 10
```

**Example 1:**

Input:

```
2
ATACGCATGACGATGCATGCAGCAT
ATA
GC
```

Output:

```
CATGACGATATAAT
```

**Example 2:**
Input:

```
3
ATGCATGCATCGACTCAGCATCAGCATCGACTA
TG
GC
AT
```

Output:

```
ACACCGACTCACACGACTA
```

My code:

I tried solving it using string in c++, I am getting :

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
what():basic_string::erase()

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <queue>
#include <stack>
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    string str, str1;
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    cin >> str;
    while (n--) {
        cin >> str1;
        int len = str1.length();int len1=str.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < len1; i++) {
            int found = str.find(str1);
            str.erase(found, found + len);
        }
    }
    cout << str;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf` is dangerous, using it and not checking the return value to see if it was successful is **very bad**. What's wrong with `cin >> n`? You should be checking the result of all your reads from `cin`.

Comment: Every time I see stackoverflow questions saying "my program reading input doesn't work" I find there is absolutely no error checking on the reads. It makes me very sad.

Comment: You also are not handling the constraints of n.

Comment: Is there a reason you mix C++ stream input and old C-style input with `scanf`? And why all those header file includes? You don't use functionality from most of them (all you need is `<iostream>` and `<string>`, and `<cstdio>` is you persist in using `scanf`).

Comment: You need to use a better way of deleting the substrings. You doo it way too often and you don't use the result of `str.find()` properly. Btw: Why is `MAX = 111`?

Comment: Also, the header for `std::string` is `<string>` not `<string.h>`

Comment: @tgmath like almost all the includes, it is not even used.  Who knows?

Comment: If your string is **not** found you do this regardless: `str.erase(found, found + len);`.

Comment: Interesting. GCC on my machine throws linker errors.  I tried it online: http://ideone.com/zyn4jU and it compiles, but I run straight into @Galik's issue.

Comment: compiles in codeblocks too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three main problems:

Number one, out of range exception on `string::erase`.
Fixed by testing that find actually returned a value:

```
if (found!=std::string::npos)
```

Number two, searching correctly.
Fixed by keeping track of `found` (it's also a `size_t` not an `int`) and searching from the next location:

```
found = str.find(str1,found);
```

Number three, using `string::erase` properly.
Fixed by using *length* of substring to erase, not *length + position*:

```
str.erase(found,len);
```

I still haven't added any input validation to your code.  You should really think about doing that yourself.

Final code:

([ideone](http://ideone.com/zyn4jU))

```
 #include <string>
 #include <iostream>

 int main()
{
    std::string str;
    std::string str1;
    int n;

    std::cin>>n;
    std::cin>>str;
    while(n--)
    {
        std::cin>>str1;
        int len = str1.length();
        size_t found = 0;
        for(unsigned int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
        {
            found = str.find(str1,found);
            if (found!=std::string::npos)
            {
                str.erase(found,len);
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout<<(str.length()?str:"0");

    return 0;
}
```

idone output for each example input (I've added your example outputs in between the `/*` `*/` marks):

```
Success time: 0 memory: 3476 signal:0
  CATGACGATATAAT
/*CATGACGATATAAT*/

Success time: 0 memory: 3476 signal:0
  ACACCGACTCACACGACTA
/*ACACCGACTCACACGACTA*/
```

Comment: still wrong answer.. i added at the end  "In case the DNA is completely consumed print 0 to indicate that there is no DNA left."  `if((str.length())!=0)
     std::cout<<str<<std::endl;
    else
        std::cout<<"0\n";`   @Baldrickk

Comment: Yes! i saw :)  @Baldrickk   in the question its written _you need to remove all occurrences of AT from the DNA first and then reform the DNA and apply the next enzyme to remove all occurrences of GC._   any other idea?

Comment: @Davidjones if you're commenting on my suggestion for a different algorithm (less erases), then you would build the new string and `std::swap` it for the original as the process for each substring.  It will result in less allocations = faster

Comment: @Baldrickk: If you want a faster algorithm I suggest the following: when a match is found overwrite it with spaces, this doesn't change the length of the sequence string and is very fast. At the end, after processing all the enzymes, do a single `remove-erase` step to remove the spaces. This step has linear complexity and again should be fast.

Comment: @Blastfurnace yep, that would work too. (creating a new string is also linear too). More than one way to skin a cat.

Comment: Well the output from the code using your two input examples is the same as your expected output. (see the bottom of my answer where I posted the output)  Are you running the same example/looking at the same answer?  Are you running my code or have you edited yours/mine?  What input/outputs are you using/getting? - as shown, it is correct with your sample input/output from the question

Comment: like for this output([link]http://imgur.com/f9wWsJL).... it should give `CGTTTG`  but your code gives different output @Baldrickk

Comment: @Davidjones URGH next time, please just paste in the input. imgur is blocked here. makes it very hard to get it.  On the plus side, fixed.

Comment: @Baldrickk   `2 ACGCATATTATGCATCATCAT  CAT A`